# Drag and a drop a range from one sheet to another sheet of the same workbook or spreadsheet in Excel/Google Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I would like to move a range of cells that contains many formulas (some using absolute reference and some others using relative reference). If I just do `Cut` and `Paste` then the relative formulas will be pointing to the wrong places.

If I was moving the range to another location on the same sheet, then I would just select the range and do `Drag` and `Drop`. How would I do this to drop to another sheet instead?

A solution for Google Sheet would work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by getting to the point that you are dragging the cells about by your mouse and then pressing the `Alt` key to enable moving off the sheet instead of just around the sheet.

Now drag down to the sheet tabs and onto the tab for the sheet you desire. You'll notice Excel changes to displaying that sheet and you can then maneuver to the correct place and drop the cells.

And if for any reason that will not work for you (Excel DOES differ on little-used features from version to version and especially between Windows and Mac, but this one seems unlikely to differ. Still...), you could test the concept using the three "control" keys (Shift, Control, and Alt) in, perhaps, combinations.

Additionally, Excel traditionally has features like this have a `Function key` (often with those control keys from above) in addition to any other method like the one at the top of this answer. I did not experiment or research that, but usually there would be one.

Finally, one could always use the expedient of opening a "new" (blank) spreadsheet in a window or on a monitor visible while the source file is open. Collect the cells and drag/drop them into the new spreadsheet. Go back and change sheets to where you want them to go, then grab them and move them back, but to where they go.

One way or the other, you can do this. But collecting them and pressing `Alt` to switch sheets and drop them seems easiest.

Comment: I can confirm using the `alt` key works but the formulas are not updated to point to the right sheet after you drop the range onto another sheet. So, they (formulas) are basically broken even though the numbers somehow don't change.